# Distributing maps at same distante in one axe

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have many maps to put into print composer. I would like to align them at the same distance each other throw vertical axe. Is there tool that align them at the same distance automatically?

[image: Column of maps that I would like distribute at the same distance each other]